# When Importing a DLL Why Do Methods Have To Be Declared Static and Extern?

Tags: c#

As the title asks, when you import a DLL such as User32.dll and declare methods to call methods on that DLL why do the methods need to be declared as Static and Extern.

I.E, this was taken from another StackOverflow answer, but demonstrates what I'm asking.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

Comment: `static` : because otherwise you would have to match up instances with the other side somehow. And deal with the `this` parameter. `extern` because you are importing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` - As they do not need instance of the class, those method's are call to system API and do not need any Initialization, can be used in static / non-static block

`extern` - The extern modifier is used to declare a method that is implemented externally. Since API methods are not declared in the class file itself, extern tell the compiler that method declared else-where.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not really know whether there are technical details to this, I'd say the reasons are:

**static**
Methods that reside in external DLLs can not be bound to any object instance. If they were bound to an object instance, the DLL would have to track which instance is calling the method every time.

**extern**
I guess this is just a keyword telling the compiler to insert code for binding the DLL instead of expecting the method to be implemented in C#.